# nginx : bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied), and port was using by "-". how to free it?

Tags: nginx, networking, centos

I made a silly mistake while using Nginx. (in CentOs)

I use symlink to point the Nginx, rename the origin directory while the Nginx process is up, and rebuild the nginx as origin one's name (to make symlink point new one)

```
the symlink nginx is pointing nginx-15
then rename nginx-15 to nginx_backup
than rebuild new nginx as nginx-15, to make symlink use new one, while origin nginx process is up. 
(I should't do so.)
```

It makes my nginx crash, and now when I run `nginx -t`, it throws the following error.

```
$ ~/apps/nginx/sbin/nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /home1/irteam/apps/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /home1/irteam/apps/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

I coulnd't run `nginx -t` as `sudo`, because the nginx process is for certain user in CentOS.

when I run netstat, it seems the port listening to `-`.

```
$ netstat -tulpn |grep 80
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.) 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

How could I use `:80` port as before?
Killed the master process & child process does not work.

Comment: `ss -putn | grep :80` may give you a better view.

Comment: I found that it's because I didn't do setcap on my nginx..